Is it allowed in Islam to work as Product consultant in Credit card Companies
I have received a job offer from a company as product consultant. Basically the company is selling credit cards and it is one of the leading credit card issuer. I would like to know is it permissible or not permissible.

In my poor and lacking understanding of Islamic law, it is not halal. Credit carts are (mostly?) based on paying interests, proportional to the sum of money people are taking as credit. Some companies try to circumvent this by taking an amount of "service fees", or whatever they will call it. A very different aspect is that "money" in time of the Prophet was not just a number printed on paper.
